# Expectation inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X, Y$ be random variables with $0 \leq X \leq Y$ and $\mathbb E[Y]=1$. Let $t>0$. Does the inequality

$$
\mathbb E[e^{tX}] \leq x\, \mathbb E[e^{tY}]+1-x
$$

where $x=\mathbb E[X]$ hold?

Comment: I think its true but I'm not sure where to start

Comment: well, it's true for sufficiently small $t$ since we can just make it small enough for the LHS to be less than 1-x. It is also true for large enough $t$ since then the difference between $Y$ and $X$ means the exponential in $Y$ dominates. The question is if it holds for all positive values of $t$.

Comment: I don't think it's for small t. If the moment-generating function exists, it should be continuous in t. Bringing all terms on one side and looking at RHS - LHS a continuous function of t, it is negative at $t=0$ for $X \neq Y$; hence, negative for small t. I'm so rusty I was lacking the confidence to post this as a counter; but I think it's not true.

Comment: That was @iMath...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This inequality does not hold in general. For example, take $X$ and $Y$ such that:

- with probability $\frac{2}{3}$, $X = 0$ and $Y = \dfrac{1}{2}$,
- with probability $\frac{1}{3}$, $X = 2$ and $Y = 2$.

In this case, the inequality would write:
$$
\frac{2}{3}+\frac{e^{2t}}{3} \leq \frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{2e^{t/2}}{3} + \frac{e^{2t}}{3}\right) + 1 - \frac{2}{3}
$$
As $t$ tend to $+\infty$, this would lead to $1 \leq \frac{2}{3}$, wich is of course absurd.

---

**However, it can be made true under certain hypotheses:** namely, if we assume that $X = ZY$ (hence $0 \leq Z \leq 1$) where $Z$ is independent of $Y$.

The convexity of the function $\exp$ then gives:
$$
e^{tX} = e^{t(Z\times Y + (1-Z)\times 0)} \leq Z e^{tY} + (1-Z)e^0
$$
for every $t > 0$. Taking the expectations, the independence gives
$$
E(e^{tX}) \leq x E(e^{tY}) + 1 - x
$$
since $x = E(YZ)=E(Z)\times 1$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

By series expansion $e^{tX} = 1 + tX + \frac{t^2X^2}{2!} + \frac{t^3X^3}{3!} + \cdots +\frac{t^nX^n}{n!} + \cdots.$

$M_X(t) = E(e^{tX}) = 1 + tm_1 + \frac{t^2m_2}{2!} + \frac{t^3m_3}{3!}+\cdots + \frac{t^nm_n}{n!}+\cdots$

Thus, $E(e^{tX}) > 1+tE[X]$ and hence $E(e^{tX})>1+tx$ since $E[X]=x$.

Similarly, $E(e^{tY})>1+t$

Now,
\begin{eqnarray}
 xE(e^{tY})+1-x &>& x(1+t)+1-x      \nonumber \\
   &>& x+tx+1-x \nonumber \\
   &>&1+tx \nonumber \\
   &>& E(e^{tX})
\end{eqnarray}

Since $X\leq Y$, thus, $E(e^{tX})\leq E(e^{tY})$ and hence the inequality follows.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in the last inequality: you know that $E(e^{tX}) \geq 1 + tx$ but you use the reversed inequality.